# index in oracle for wild card

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have a column test with following values, AAABBBCCC , A1ABBBCCC,AAADDDCCC

I can create an index for the column to find the exact values faster but user can enter something like AAAxxxCCC. in this case the x is like wild card and both the first and the 3rd value should be retrieved. Or AxABBBCCC then the first and second should be retrieved

Can I create function-based index for the column, or how do I implement such behavior in Oracle?

Comment: How long do you expect the first sequence `AAA` to be? The more specific it is, the faster the query. You may want to force the user for a longer prefix as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the wild card is in the middle or the end and the leading characters before the wildcard match a relatively small number of records, then you should use the `LIKE` operator. Replace the "`x`" with `_` :

```
WHERE column LIKE 'AAA___CCC'
```

If your user can't use `_` and insists on an '`x`' wildcard, replace it with a `_` in your SQL:

```
WHERE column LIKE REPLACE('AAAxxxCCC','x','_')
```

This is my primary answer. It won't be fast, however, if you have a ton of rows starting with AAA. If you run into this problem, then there are some possibilities depending on what patterns are common. If you always look at the first three characters and the last three, you can SUBSTR them out and index that function:

```
CREATE INDEX i_first3 on mytable(SUBSTR(mycolumn,1,3));
CREATE INDEX i_last3 on mytable(SUBSTR(mycolumn,-3,3));

SELECT * 
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE SUBSTR(mycolumn,1,3) = 'AAA'
   AND SUBSTR(mycolumn,-3,3) = 'CCC'
```

Obviously this won't work if the user can wild card any position and you can't predict which one. But you can do some edgy things like creating a separate functioned based index for each number of final characters and then based on the value the user supplies, find the number of characters after the last wildcard and use a substring on that, plus a LIKE on the rest:

```
CREATE INDEX i_last1 on mytable(SUBSTR(mycolumn,-1),mycolumn);
CREATE INDEX i_last2 on mytable(SUBSTR(mycolumn,-2),mycolumn);
CREATE INDEX i_last3 on mytable(SUBSTR(mycolumn,-3),mycolumn);
CREATE INDEX i_last4 on mytable(SUBSTR(mycolumn,-4),mycolumn);
CREATE INDEX i_last5 on mytable(SUBSTR(mycolumn,-5),mycolumn);
CREATE INDEX i_last6 on mytable(SUBSTR(mycolumn,-6),mycolumn);
CREATE INDEX i_last7 on mytable(SUBSTR(mycolumn,-7),mycolumn);
...etc..

SELECT * 
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE mycolumn LIKE REPLACE('AxABBBCCC','x','_')
   AND SUBSTR(mycolumn,-7) = SUBSTR('AxABBBCCC',-7)
```

That will use `i_last7` doing a seek (binary search) on the last 7 digits, then scan through the leaf nodes applying the `LIKE` operator on the whole `mycolumn` column which is the second column in the index. It could perform a lot better than `LIKE` with only one character before a wildcard.

You can also reverse the value with `REVERSE` and index that, then decide whether to use `LIKE` on the normal value (if the wildcard is further into the value), or on the reverse of the value (if the wildcard is near the front).

```
 CREATE INDEX i_reverse on mytable(REVERSE(mycolumn));

SELECT * 
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE REVERSE(mycolumn) LIKE REVERSE(REPLACE('xxABBBCCC','x','_'))
```

vs.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE mycolumn LIKE REPLACE('AAABBBCxx','x','_')
```

Anyway, you get the point - your options depend on your query patterns and your data. Hopefully the simple `LIKE` without any function-based index will satisfy your needs and you won't need all this extra stuff. You won't know until you try it and see how it performs.

Lastly and hopefully not too often, you can add a parallel attribute to the table so that if Oracle sees a wildcard at the beginning of the string and goes for a full table scan, at least it will read it in parallel with direct path reads.

Comment: the x could be at any position do is hard to preduct. like is the first choice of course but if there are 32mil rows and just 500-5000 satisfy the wild card at any position the index should be created to make it faster because like will slow the query too much

Comment: LIKE uses indexes. They aren't incompatible. It's just that the number of index leaf blocks it has to scan can be excessively large if you are only matching on the first character or two, and of course is useless if you are matching on *no* leading characters (wildcard in first position). I have given you lots of options for how to work around this and get better performance.

Comment: you mention that LIKE uses indexes. it means if I have one column col1 varchar2(3) and I will create an index on this column. if I use in Where clause  col1 like 'abc' so there is no wild card _ or % symbol , Oracle uses an index to retrieve the value? probably it internaly rewrite the where clause to col1 = 'abc'.? what is Oracle doing if 'ab_'? how can use the index ?

Comment: yes, Oracle will use the index if you say LIKE 'abc'. It may or may not use the index if you say LIKE 'a%'. It will not use the index if you say LIKE '%bc', or if it does it'll be a full scan rather than a range scan. It tries to make the best decision.

Comment: B-tree indexes are searched from the root node through branch nodes and then to leaf nodes, following pointers to key value ranges. Once they get to the leaf nodes and find the start of the matching key values, they scan forward row-by-row within blocks, and then jump linked-list to the next adjacent block and until it gets to rows that no longer match/out of range. Durign this leaf block scan it can apply any operator to the key values... it's no longer seeking, it's just scanning full key values. So, indexes are used for more than just equality... they can support >, <, BETWEEN, LIKE, etc..

Comment: But, the more scanning they have to do, the worse it will perform. So yes, your LIKEs can use indexes, but that may or may not produce acceptable performance. It all depends on where your first wildcard is and how many rows have the same value left of that wildcard. The binary search / seek stage of index access will only work up to the wildcard. It's leaf node scan from there on.

Answer (score 0):

As already written, the distribution of the data can be unequal depending on the position within the data column and an index access may not be worthwhile at all.

It is therefore probably advisable to leave this estimation to the database, which keeps statistics on it. This means building an index for each position of the data column:

```
-- Create Table with random data
create table my_table (idx number, pattern varchar2(4));
insert into my_table select level, dbms_random.string('U', 4) from dual connect by level <= 1000000;

-- Column 1 is unevenly distributed, 50% = A
update my_table set pattern= substr(pattern,1,1)||'A'||substr(pattern,3,2) where rownum <= 500000;

-- Column 2 is unevenly distributed, almost completely = B
update my_table set pattern= substr(pattern,2,1)||'B'||substr(pattern,3,2) where rownum <= 999000;

-- Build indexes
create index s1 on my_table (substr(pattern, 1, 1));
create index s2 on my_table (substr(pattern, 2, 1));
create index s3 on my_table (substr(pattern, 3, 1));
create index s4 on my_table (substr(pattern, 4, 1));
```

Depending on the frequency, the execution plans are:

```
select max(idx)from my_table where substr(pattern, 1, 1) = 'A' and substr(pattern, 3, 1) = 'C';
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name     | Rows  | Bytes  | Cost | Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |          |     1 |      9 |  263 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |   SORT AGGREGATE                       |          |     1 |      9 |      |          |
|   2 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | MY_TABLE | 20326 | 182934 |  263 | 00:00:01 |
|   3 |     BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS        |          |       |        |      |          |
|   4 |      BITMAP AND                        |          |       |        |      |          |
|   5 |       BITMAP CONVERSION FROM ROWIDS    |          |       |        |      |          |
| * 6 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                | S3       | 37358 |        |   14 | 00:00:01 |
|   7 |       BITMAP CONVERSION FROM ROWIDS    |          |       |        |      |          |
| * 8 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                | S1       | 37358 |        |  203 | 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 6 - access(SUBSTR("PATTERN",3,1)='C')
* 8 - access(SUBSTR("PATTERN",1,1)='A')


select max(idx) from my_table where substr(pattern, 2, 1) = 'B' and substr(pattern, 3, 1) = 'C';
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name     | Rows  | Bytes  | Cost | Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |          |     1 |      9 |  415 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |   SORT AGGREGATE                       |          |     1 |      9 |      |          |
| * 2 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | MY_TABLE | 37358 | 336222 |  415 | 00:00:01 |
| * 3 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | S3       | 37358 |        |   14 | 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 2 - filter(SUBSTR("PATTERN",2,1)='B')
* 3 - access(SUBSTR("PATTERN",3,1)='C')
```